# Pairs of galaxies that look like the Whirlpool-galaxy with companion?

Tags: galaxy, galaxy-cluster

I need examples of pairs of galaxies that look like the Whirlpool-galaxy with its companion NGC-5195. That is spirals with a companion galaxy attached to one arm, see picture below. I already know about Arp86 and NGC-4911 may be the spiral galaxy of such a pair also. But are there more?

[image]

Comment: Did you try and image google [merging galaxies](https://www.google.dk/search?q=merging+galaxies), [galaxy close encounter](https://www.google.dk/search?q=galaxy+close+encounter), [companion galaxy](https://www.google.com/search?q=companion+galaxy), or something similar?

Comment: https://esahubble.org/images/heic0810bv/ however this pair of galaxies are not actually connected, the smaller one is a background object.